# How to show vertical scroll bar in UITableView in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am just a new learner in `iOS`.

I want to do my `UITableView` like following pic's scrollbar.

[image]

I want to show that in my `UITableView`.

And can i also add custom text into these bar and?

Thanks for your helping. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView` method of your table view data source. As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) says, the method returns an array with the index list that is shown on the right. For example, you may return an array with letters from 'A' to 'Z'.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a scroll bar, that's an index list. You need to implement the `UITableViewDataSource sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:` method to provide that data. You also need to implement the `UITableViewDataSource tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:` method as well.

Use the constant `UITableViewIndexSearch` to get the search symbol.

Comment: Apple provides several table based sample apps that perform this function. Look at the "The Elements" and "TableViewSuite" sample apps for code.